# PHP PDO statement not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo, bindparam

I'm having a problem with my PDO statement. I have an in active pipe `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` watching for errors and nothing is coming in, I even piped my `mysql.log` file no errors there either.

- if i `echo $_POST['sfl']` it will print an integer ie.(4)
- If I change the `:sfl` param to just a regular integer ie. `"SELECT * FROM station WHERE SFL = '4'"` it will query and pull the data fine.

> I've removed error checks from the code for clarity

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM station WHERE SFL = :sfl";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':sfl', $_POST['sfl']);
$stmt->execute();
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($result);   
}
```

**Question:** Why isn't php binding my `$_POST['sfl']` variable to my statement?

Comment: What if you do `WHERE SFL = ':sfl'` ?

Comment: @sinazza yea I tried that to still nothing printing.

Comment: @JordanDavis Every thing seems fine but what if you try passing an extra argument to bind param  to tell that the parameter is int `$stmt->bindParam(':sfl', $_POST['sfl'], PDO::PARAM_INT)`

Comment: Quotes around the placeholder will not work. Can you do a `var_dump($_POST['sfl'])`? Perhaps there are other (invisible...) characters that are part of the variable like spaces.

Comment: @jeroen there isn't any spaces I'm sure, I even ran it again, this is the output for your `var_dump` string(1) "3"

Comment: @JordanDavis What do you see in yout logfile?

Comment: @Jens nothing on either log files php or mysql thats whats driving me insane.

Comment: @BasheerAhmed yea I tried assigning the data type `PDO::PARAM_INT` still didn't do work.

Comment: Post your full code including your connection

Comment: Does `execute()` return successfully? Have you checked `$stmt->errorInfo()`?

Comment: @deceze yea outputs 0's (no errors).

Comment: I'm fixing this application for a client so I'm assuming at this point its got to be a some type of configuration problem, when it was originally built... since I think I've literally tried every attempt to debug lol. I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling, and then re-running the code.

Comment: @JordanDavis Try passing fix value to bindParam and see what it does..